# How can I run the wpf project with debug(f11)?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

When I run my wpf project in visual studio with f11 key it doesn't work with debug? I'm using MVVM. I can run different project with debug in other types of data binding that I have reviewed on the internet. How can I run this project with the debug?

```
<Window x:Class="MertTestPremium.LoginView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MertTestPremium"
    xmlns:models="clr-namespace:MertTestPremium.Models"
    xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MertTestPremium.ViewModels"       
    xmlns:p = "clr-namespace:MertTestPremium.Resources.Language"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"     
    Title="Login" Height="500" Width="350" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" >

<Window.DataContext>
    <viewmodels:LoginViewModel x:Name="viewmodels"/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>     

    <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Image/mertlogo.jpg" Width="100" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="20"/>
    <Rectangle Width="280" Height="240" Fill="White" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="35,0,35,100" RadiusY="34" RadiusX="34">
        <Rectangle.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect Color="#FFBBBBBB" BlurRadius="15" RenderingBias="Quality" ShadowDepth="1"/>
        </Rectangle.Effect>
    </Rectangle>
    <Grid Width="280" Height="240" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,100">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10">
            <TextBox x:Name="UserN_txtBox" Text="{Binding LoginModel.UserName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="{x:Static p:Localization.Login_UserN_txtBox}" Width="250" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" Margin="0,10" FontSize="15"/>
            <PasswordBox models:PasswordBoxMVVMAttachedProperties.EncryptedPassword ="{Binding LoginModel.Password, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="Pass_txtBox" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="{x:Static p:Localization.Login_Pass_txtBox}" Width="250" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintPasswordBox}" Margin="0,10" FontSize="15" PasswordChanged="Pass_txtBox_PasswordChanged" />
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
    <Button x:Name="login_btn" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding LoginModel}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,85" Width="150" Content="{x:Static p:Localization.Login_login_btn}" />
    <Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="320,-4,-5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="35" >
        <Image.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Image">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Image/close-32px.png"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Image/close-24px.png" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>

</Grid>
```

Comment: What happens when you try? Have you tried F5? Or right-click the project and Debug -> Start New Instance, or Debug menu -> Start debugging?

Comment: Are you expecting to be able to step through xaml somehow?

Comment: What I expected is that it stops with debug as soon as it comes to the c # part just like other programs.

Comment: That isn't what f11 does. I think you're understanding of debugging is mistaken. You need a break point and you need to run with debugging then it'll break when processing hits your break point. No break point or not starting with debugging will mean it just runs.

Comment: Are you sure? When i try F11 Key in  different project i could use how like i want.
for example : [link](https://github.com/8/AvalonDockMVVM) . Can you run it with F11?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't step through XAML code (which is a drawback with WPF where XAML errors are now Runtime and not Compiler which makes debugging that more annoying)

You can start debugging by pressing **f5** in order to step into a function you'll need to set a breakpoint where you want the program to halt by pressing the **f9** key which will then give you the ability to step into/out using **f11** or step over using **f10**.

If you're looking for a binding error you'll need to look through the Output window and find a line starting with the following **System.Windows.Data Error: ...**

Comment: I don't want to debug in XAMl. But when I run this code, it should stop with debug when it first comes to the c # section.

Comment: The code you posted in XAML code not C# code. If you want to debug C# you'll need to ensure that a breakpoint is put at a section of code that is executed. If you want it on the first section of c# possible the breakpoint must be located within the constructor of the class, which based on the XAML code would be the constructor for the view model.

Comment: i could encounter project that didn't know and i could want to watch without breakpoint thus i could use F11 key (step into). Can you check it for better understand me?
 (https://github.com/8/AvalonDockMVVM) . Can you run it with F11?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't being confused by the output window when the app is running? As far as I know you can only step into a function when the program has either paused or hit a break point allowing you to take control.